# When does the Putnam release solutions to this year's exam? Has anyone released their own solutions?

Tags: reference-request, contest-math

I was just wondering when the Putnam committee releases the solutions to this year's exam or if anyone has posted their own solutions.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned on [Kiran Kedlaya's webpage](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/):

> Those [official solutions] appear in the official exam summary, along with results and statistics, in the American Mathematical Monthly sometime in the year following the competition, usually in October. (One typically also finds solutions in Mathematics Magazine in early spring.)

A set of unofficial solutions, compiled from various sources, may be found on that same webpage.